# How to offer full app download link from app clip

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-appclips

### How to offer the full app once user is done with app clip action?

In the following screenshot from [What's new in App Clips](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10097/) WWDC 2022 video, once the users are done ordering food, they are given option to download the full app.

Is there a specific UI configuration to use?

From the [What's new in App Clips](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10097/) WWDC 2022.

[image: What's new in App Clips]

#### Is it possible to customize the `download banner`?

Say remove the `Get the full app`?

Screenshot from 2020 video.
[image: Design great App Clips]

Answer (score 0):

With `UIKit`, refer to [recommending your app to App Clip users](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/recommending_your_app_to_app_clip_users) with `SKOverlay` and `SKOverlayAppClipConfiguration` object.

With `SwiftUI`, `appStoreOverlay()` could be used to provide the download option.

Note: To find the `App Identifier` go to the AppStoreConnect.apple.com -> General -> App Information and locate `Apple Id` (`An automatically generated ID assigned to your app.`).

Use it to trigger the AppStoreOverlay.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showRecommended = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Recommended App") {
            showRecommended.toggle()
        }
        .appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $showRecommended) {
            SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "1440611372", position: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Credits: How to recommend another app [using appStoreOverlay()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-recommend-another-app-using-appstoreoverlay)